# Class instance null after instantiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Update: As mentioned in the comments below, Targeting target_manager; (in MakeAbility) is null. This seems to be the root of the issue, but why is it null?

===========

In the code below, I create an instance of the class PartAttack and then assign it the reference for my target manager.

The first debug log returns PartAttack. The second returns null.

public Targeting target_manager (in the first script) is assigned in the inspector to a gameobject with the Targeting script on it.

What am I doing wrong? Why is this not assigning the target manager correctly?

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;

public class MakeAbility : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BlockScriptableObject block;

    public IDictionary<string, IAbility> abilities_parts = new Dictionary<string, IAbility>();


    public Targeting target_manager;
    public PartAttack part_attack = new PartAttack();

    private void Start()
    {
        part_attack.block_attack_damage = block.attack_damage;
        part_attack.target_manager = target_manager;
        Debug.Log(part_attack);
        Debug.Log(part_attack.target_manager);

        abilities_parts.Add("part_attack", part_attack);

    }

}

    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;


[System.Serializable]
public class PartAttack: IAbility
{
    public Targeting target_manager;

    public void Use()
    {

    }

}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Targeting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int max_targets = 3;
    public string current_target = null;
    public List<Combatant> list_of_targetable = new List <Combatant>();

    public BlockScriptableObject block; // The abilityblock

    public GameObject target_clickfield_char1;
    public Combatant character_slot_1;

}
```

Comment: public Targeting target_manager is assigned in the inspector to a gameobject with the Targeting script on it.

Comment: `public Targeting target_manager;` (in MakeAbility) and `public Targeting target_manager;` (in PartAttack) are not the same object.

Comment: That's initially true but dont I set the PartAttack target_manager to the same instance as the other?

Comment: Is `public Targeting target_manager;` (in MakeAbility) non-null?

Comment: Wow, you're right, Targeting target_manager is null when I put the debug at the start of the Start() function. Why could that be?

Comment: public Targeting target_manager = new Targeting();

    public PartAttack part_attack = new PartAttack();


    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(target_manager); // <<<<< this debug is null

Comment: You don't create instances of type MonoBehaviour using new or a constructor. The only way to create a new instance is by adding it to an existing GameObject using gameObjectReference.AddComponent<YourType>()! Didn't you say there is already the according GameObject referenced in the Inspector? why do you use `public Targeting target_manager = new Targeting();` (which is not allowed) then?

Answer (score 2):

TargetManager does not appear to be instantiated anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set TargetManager to a memory allocation. This is done with instantiation.

You can either create a constructor for the aggregate class that will allocate this memory by instantiating the variable, or you can set target_manager to some new memory allocation in your main function.

```
public Targeting target_manager = new Targeting();
```

C# is fast. And we can't expect to see an instantiated object so soon after the pointers are declared. I understand that there is a game object elsewhere in the system that will eventually assign it, but for your debugging script, that hasn't happened yet.

You need to assign it to an empty object inside of a constructor if you intend to always have something there. Especially if you write a line of code that is going to access it immediately after declaring its existence. Don't rely on other code that exists in a different object. To the computer that code is very far away.

This wont hurt your later assignment, as reassignment isn't going to break anything, it just allocates more memory somewhere else.

If you're worried about memory leaks, dispose the object before redeclaring it.

Comment: Adding the specific line you mention did unfortunately not change any outcome. I added it in each class individually and in both classes together. The First debug is still PartAttack and the second is still null. Interesting answer though, very understandable and interesting in it's own right.

Comment: Because of this, I'm going to say, we need to see some more code to help.

Comment: I'm adding the targeting class now. A thought occured, could this be due to different instanciation rules when one doesnt derive from monobehaviour?

Comment: You don't create instances of type `MonoBehaviour` using `new` or a constructor. The only way to create a new instance is by adding it to an existing GameObject using `gameObjectReference.AddComponent<YourType>()`!